# What is the difference between constructing and axiomatizing a well-ordering?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, well-orders

In my lecture on mathematical logic, we said that the constructible universe $(\mathbb{L}, \in)$ is a model for the Axiom of Choice because all well-orderings are constructible, that is, definable by an FO-formula.

Later on in the lecture, it is shown, using the back-and-forth method to construct an isomorphism from a well-ordered structure to a non-well-ordered structure, that well-orderings are not FO-axiomatizable.

Intuitively, that seems like a contradiction to me. Could someone explain to me how well-orderings, or any class of sets, can be constructible but not axiomatizable?

Comment: "[..]because all well-orderings are constructible[..]" -- this might be a misunderstanding (or maybe just an unfortunate choice of words). $(L;\in)$ is a model of choice because it has a (uniformly) definable well-order of its universe. Not all well-orders are 'constructible' - in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two notions are completely unrelated to one another.

Being constructible is a specific set theoretic property. It means that you are created by iterating pointwise "taking definable subsets", generally starting from the empty set. It has little to do with model theory, in general.

Being axiomatizable has little to do with set theory itself. It means that in a given first-order language which includes a binary relation symbol $<$, you are able to write axioms which guarantee that $<$ is interpreted as a well-ordering of the model.

In the case of well-orders, this is not a first-order property, and a quick ultrapower argument can show that any well-ordered structure is elementary equivalent to one which is not well-ordered. Therefore there is no theory which ensures the $<$ symbol is interpreted as a well-order.

Comment: "[..]a quick ultrapower argument[..]" -- So it's not just me who thinks of the compactness theorem as an application of Los' Theorem...

Comment: I don't think about compactness as a consequence of Łoś, since it is consistent that compactness fails but Łoś holds. But I also find it more natural to think about ultrapowers when it comes to violating well-foundedness, because we also know exactly when the argument fails (i.e., when the ultrafilter is $\sigma$-complete).

Comment: "[..] consistent that compactness fails but Łoś holds[..]" -- In that model you don't have a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$, I suppose?

Comment: @Stefan: In that model you don't any free ultrafilters on any set, no. :)

Comment: I see. Fortunately they do exist :P

Comment: Stefan, I am happy for you that you are able to believe that anything exists! That is wonderful. Now, since I don't believe that you exist (I don't believe that you don't exist either, for the record), I can't quite take your word about this. So I'll stick with my insistence to not believe and not take "existence" as an intrinsically-meaningful term. :P

Comment: Don't you rain on my Platonic parade -- I'm just (trying) to get used to it!

Comment: Stefan: I don't believe in the existence of such a parade, so I don't see the problem with my raining on it. (I also don't believe in the existence of rain, but that might be because I grew up in the desert...)

Comment: Surely, by now, Vienna must have done its job convincing you of the existence of rain.

Comment: Stefan, you'd think that, but not all that much actually.